# AngularJS: Can't use JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Here is the JSOn file that is retrived from my API:

```
{  
   "pid":12925,
   "a":"How is this a palindrome hexagon oriennted? (digits should not be repeated)",
   "c":"",
   "opts":{  
      "A":"216",
      "B":"69",
      "C":"72",
      "D":"96",
      "answer":"X"
   },
   "ansDetails":{  
      "ans":"<p>This is question is invalud</p>",
      "ansPid":null,
      "pt":"X"
   }
}
```

The angular code that i wrote:

Controller:

```
testControllers.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams' ,function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
  $http.get('http://url_of_theapi').success(function(data) {
  $scope.questions = data;
    $scope.parseInt = parseInt;
  });
}]);
```

View:

```
<section class="a">
    <div class="mcq">
      <div>
        <h3>QUESTION</h3>
        <p class>{{questions.pid}}</p>    
     <ul>
              <li class= "optlist" ng-repeat="item in questions.opts">
              <label class="formgroup">
              <input type="radio" name = "q">
              {{item.val}}
             </label>
             </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

How do I fix this? Is this an Issue of Angular or the JSON?

The problem: The data from the JSON is not getting displayed.

**Update**: The error is due to:

*Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://url_of_api. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).*

How do I fix this?

Comment: You really haven't explained what problem you have is. There are definitely issues in the code, but your question should include a proper problem description so people know which part to look at. *"cant use json"* is a meaningless description

Comment: Sorry. The data from the JSON files is not getting displayed...

Comment: Have you logged  your `data` variable? Are you sure it is automatically being parsed to a JSON object? If your API doesn't put out the proper header showing that it is JSON `$http` might just be retrieving it as text. If the API is on a different domain you might not be getting it because of Cross-Origin security restrictions. Add a `.fail` callback to see if you are getting errors

Comment: Its because of the cross origin security restrictions, How do I fix that?

Comment: You have to add the ACAO header in your backend to the response. But it depends how on the technology you use. Or you have to have to run the backend and the client from the same address like `http://example.com`

Answer (score 0):

`{{ item.val }}` doesn't exist ,

either use `{{ item }}`

or if you want the key also make your `ngRepeat` like:

```
`ng-repeat="(key, val) in questions.opts"`
```

so in first iteration:

```
{{ key }} => a
{{ val }} => 216
```

Comment: Thanks. But even `questions.t` is not being displayed.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `questions.pid` and  I didn't downvote

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to convert your json to an object using `JSON.parse(jsonString)` or other available functions.